# For loop to retry an async function (sequlize.authenticate)

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, for-loop, asynchronous

I would like to have my microservice waiting until the database becomes available.
(I have a sidecar Cloud SQL proxy that needs some time for the database connection).

So I was thinking of writing a for loop that attempts a connect and retries after a defined time.

Currently, the code looks as follows, but it doesn't seem to wait before reconnecting.

```js
private class Database {
  static async connectDatabase() {
    try {
      const retries = 20;

      const tryTimeout = async (currentTry, retries) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) =>
          setTimeout(function () {
            logger.info(`Try: ${currentTry}, ${retries} retries left.`);
          }, 1000));
      };

      for (let i = 1; i <= retries; i++) {
        try {
          // Establish database connection
          await SequelizeConnection.authenticate()
            .then(() => {
              logger.info(
                "*** Database connection has been established successfully."
              );
            })
            .catch(async (err) => {
              logger.info("Error in connect database function: ", err);
              throw err;
            });
          await SeqzelizeConnectionHealthcheck.authenticate()
            .then(() => {
              logger.info(
                "*** Database connection for healthcheck has been established successfully."
              );
            })
            .catch(async (err) => {
              logger.error(
                "Error in connect database function for healthcheck: ",
                err
              );
              throw err;
            });
        } catch (error) {
          logger.error("Error in connectDB retry function");
          await tryTimeout(i, retries - i);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error("Error in connect database function: ", error);
    }
  }
}
```

I was thinking of creating a retry wrapper function and tried some retry libraries but without success.

Comment: try adding `await` before `SequelizeConnection.authenticate()`
You can see an example [HERE](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html): in the "Testing the connection" section

Comment: Thanks for that, it was definitely missing! I have also added a promise to the setTimeout function and update the question. Currently it's still crashing.

Comment: a) if everything goes fine and does not throw an error, you are still doing a retry (without waiting!) instead of returning from the function b) your `tryTimeout` does never call `resolve`

Comment: You shouldn't be using both `await` and `.then()`/`.catch()` - they are alternative ways of waiting for promises to resolve.  The code that is in the `.then()` should just be on the next line after the `await`.  The code that is in the `.catch()` should be in a `try ... catch(err) { ... } ` around the `await` line.

Comment: Also "SeqzelizeConnectionHealthcheck" has a typo "Seqzelize.."?

Comment: A couple more issues - you're not actually resolving the timeout promise, so you will be `await`ing on that forever.  Also you're not `break`ing out of the `for` loop when you successfully connect, so it would in theory continue to retry the connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, there are a few issues in the code.  Mainly that you're mixing `await` with `.then()`/`.catch()`, not resolving the promise from the wait and not breaking out of the `for` loop when the connections are successful.

To illustrate this, I've reformatted your method a bit and extracted some functions so it's hopefully clearer.  In the snippet below I'm simulating the database connection succeeding after 3 tries and the healthcheck database connection succeeding after 5 tries.

I've also changed the logic a bit so that it makes the main database and healthcheck database connections concurrently and retries them independently - you don't want to be retrying the main database connection again just because the healthcheck one failed, so for this I created a `retryUntilResolved` function that will retry the given function until it resolves, or until the maximum number of retries has been reached.

```js
// Mocks purely for snippet
const resolveNthTime = nth => {
  let callCount = 0;
  return () => ++callCount >= nth
    ? Promise.resolve()
    : Promise.reject('failed!');
}
const SequelizeConnection = { authenticate: resolveNthTime(3) };
const SequelizeConnectionHealthcheck = { authenticate: resolveNthTime(5) };


// Example
const pause = ms =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const retryUntilResolved = (waitMs, maxRetries) => async func => {
  let tries = 0;

  while (true) {
    try {
      return await func();
    } catch(err) {
      if (tries++ < maxRetries) await pause(waitMs);
      else return err;
    }
  }
};


const authenticateDatabase = async () => {
  try {
    await SequelizeConnection.authenticate();
    console.info("Database connection established");
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn("Error connecting to database: ", err);
    throw err;
  }
};

const authenticateHealthcheck = async () => {
  try {
    await SequelizeConnectionHealthcheck.authenticate();
    console.info("Database connection for healthcheck established");
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn("Error connecting to healthcheck database: ", err);
    throw err;
  }
};

class Database {
  static async connectDatabase() {
    const maxRetries = 20;
    const msBeforeRetry = 1000;
    const retry = retryUntilResolved(msBeforeRetry, maxRetries);

    try {
      await Promise.all([
        retry(authenticateDatabase),
        retry(authenticateHealthcheck),
      ]);
      console.info('Both connections established');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Could not establish both connections');
    }
  }
}

Database.connectDatabase();
```

Comment: One further thing I noticed - you might want to `throw` an error after you have used all retries unsuccessfully so that the async `connectDatabase` method rejects.  At the moment it will eventually resolve whether the connection was successful or not.  This may or may not be important to your use-case.

Comment: Hi Robin, many thanks for your code! It works beautifully and I have added a Promise.reject() retryUntilSolved function and quit the app upon failure. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @lucbas Just made a small edit to remove the `throw lastError;` line from `retryUntilResolved()` function - it was left over code from something I was trying out and wasn't ever reached because the error is returned in the catch.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `resolve()` in `setTimeout()`.
Please see below example. It is the code that assumes that authenticate() always fails.

```js
async function connectDatabase() {
  try {
    const retries = 20;

    const tryTimeout = async (currentTry, retries) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) =>
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log(`Try: ${currentTry}, ${retries} retries left.`);
          resolve();
        }, 1000));
    };

    for (let i = 1; i <= retries; i++) {
      try {
        // Establish database connection
        await sequelizeConnection_authenticate()
          .then(() => {
            console.log(
              "*** Database connection has been established successfully."
            );
          })
          .catch(async (err) => {
            console.log("Error in connect database function: ", err);
            throw err;
          });
        await seqzelizeConnectionHealthcheck_authenticate()
          .then(() => {
            console.log(
              "*** Database connection for healthcheck has been established successfully."
            );
          })
          .catch(async (err) => {
            console.log(
              "Error in connect database function for healthcheck: ",
              err
            );
            throw err;
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in connectDB retry function");
        await tryTimeout(i, retries - i);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in connect database function: ", error);
  }
}

async function sequelizeConnection_authenticate() {
  return new Promise((_, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      reject();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function seqzelizeConnectionHealthcheck_authenticate() {
  return new Promise((_, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      reject();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

connectDatabase();
```